# Finding subgroups and normal subgroups of a specific semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers, semidirect-product

Let $A = \{ m2^n \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \} \le (\mathbb{Q},+)$ and let $T=\langle t\rangle$ be infinite cyclic that acts on $A$ by the rule $at=2a$. Then let $G = T \ltimes A$. What I would like to show that it has the maximality condition on normal subgroups, or equivalently to show that it does not have an infinite proper chain of normal subgroups $K_1 < K_2 <$ ...

My suspicion is that the only proper normal subgroup of $G$ is $A$, and was trying to show it. Could you please give me some suggestion on how to proceed?

---

I was not sure what the rule $at=2a$ really meant so I tought it could have meant that the operation induced is
$$(k_1t,m_12^{n_1})(k_2t,m_22^{n_2}) = ((k_1+k_2)t, m_12^{n_1 + k_2} + m_22^{n_2})$$
if I am wrong could you please clarify?

---

My idea was to show that the only possible subgroups of $G$ are subgroups of $A$ and then show that subgroups of $A$ are those that have "bounded denominators", for example $2^n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (so includining negatives). And then show that coniugating these "finite denominators" groups, we "go out of bounds", showing that the only normal subgroup of $G$ is $A$.

Comment: Since $T$ has infinitely many normal subgroups, there are infinitely many normal subgroups of $G$ that contain $A$. But the subgroups of $T$ satisfy the maximality condition. So you need to show that all normal subgroups of $G$ contain $A$.

Comment: I am having dificulties with showing that if a group does not contain $A$, then it is not normal

Comment: I think I have reduced the problem to a question on the structure of the subgroups of $A$. I would need to show that given $H\le A$ there exists $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall m2^n \in H$ we have $d \le n$.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong, it is not true that all nontrivial normal subgroups of $G$ contain $A$. The normal subgroups of $G$ contained in $A$ are of the form $A_k = \{mk2^n : m,n \in {\mathbb Z} \}$ for odd $k \ge 1$.

Comment: So if that is true, we might have that there exists a proper chain of normal subgroups: $A_3 < A_{3^2} < A_{3^3} <$ ... which contradicts that maximality on normal subgroups. Am I correct?

Comment: No, you have your inequality signs the wrong way round, that is an infinite *descending* chain. The maximality condition holds for normal subgroups of $G$ contained in $A$ and also for subgroups of $T \cong G/A$, so it holds for $G$. I will write out a proper answer when I have time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N \lhd G$ with $N \le A$. If $0 \ne g \in N$, then so is $t^{-n}gt^n = 2^ng$ for all $n \in {\mathbb Z}$, so we can choose $g$ to be an odd positive integer. Then by choosing $g = k$ to be the least such odd positive integer, it is straightforward to show that $N = A_k := \{km2^n : m,n \in {\mathbb Z}\}$. Furthermore, since $A_k \le A_l$ if and only if $l|k$, we see that subgroups $A_k$ satisfy the ascending chain condition.

Now let $1 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots$ be an ascending chain of normal subgroups of $G$. By what we proved above the chain $1 \le A \cap N_1 \le A \cap N_2 \le\cdots$ must stabilize so, for some $t>0$,  $A \cap N_i$ is constant for all $i > t$.

Also, since $G/A \cong ({\mathbb Z},+)$ has ACC on subgroups, the chain $1 \le AN_1 \le AN_2 \le\cdots$ must stabilize so, for some $s \ge t$ both $(A \cap N_i)$ and $AN_i$ are constant. It is straightforward to show that this implies that the original series $1 \le N_1 \le N_2 \le \cdots$ is constant for $i \ge s$.

Comment: You mean $t^{-n}gt^n = 2^n g$, right?

Comment: Yes, corrected.